# Typeset the standard "Moon" symbol

Tags: formatting, symbols, astronomy

As it says on the tin, I want a way to typeset the astronomical symbol for the moon, which is a crescent. I also want this in such a way that I could integrate it into a button as a label, like the rest of the astronomical symbols included, such as $\oplus$ for Earth.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's a native one for Mathematica but on Mac for the default Mathematica font `"\:263d"` should do it (it's the unicode char point for ☽ according to copying that in and looking at the box-form).

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't thought to check unicode for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

The typeset the astronomical symbol for the moon, which is a crescent, is built-in as `\[Moon]`...

Comment: Oh interesting I thought I had tried that and got nothing